# Flutter IOS app crashes after few day of installation

Tags: flutter

Friends,

I have peculiar issue in Flutter.I installed app in device(iPad) successfully in sandbox mode with my developer account. After few days when I try to open app it crashes. It is properly running app. Anyone can help in this issue. Where can i see the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound likes your distribution certificate is expired. 
Verify while your app cannot be opened, it's still running in the background.
If that's the case, you will need to redistribute (rebuild) your app.

Which type your developer account is?
As far as I know, default development distribution expiration for a free account is 7 days and a paid account is 1 year.